# ImportError: No module named os uwsgi + django + linux

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I am trying to configure uswgi with nginx

The steps I followed are:

Install NGINX

```
sudo yum install nginx
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start &
```

Pip

```
yum -y install python-pip
```

Install Python

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.6.tgz  
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure  
make  
sudo make install
```

Install Uwsgi

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Install  Django

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django
```

Command

```
uwsgi --socket /tmp/wsgi.sock --module App.wsgi:application --chmod-socket=666 -H /usr/local/bin/python --master --processes 4 --threads 2 &
```

**Error**

```
   "wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
        import os
    ImportError: No module named os
    unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

wsgi.py content

```
10: import os
11: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "SecurityInsights.settings")
12:
13: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
14: application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And there is no problem while loading os module in console

```
/usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 18:55:35) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
```

**EDIT**

as per @ZZY suggesstion I checked the python version in `python manage.py shell`, it is different 2.6.9 than global 2.7.6. Is this making any difference?

Comment: What happen when you "import os" in "python manage.py shell"? And what is "Python version" printed in uwsgi's logs?

Comment: oh it is different 2.6.9

Comment: "import os" works fine. How I can upgrade python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you did need all your stuff running in Python2.7. Then you may try to re-install uwsgi with Python27 support:

```
sudo pip uninstall uwsgi

wget http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
cd <dir>
sudo python2.7 uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python core python27
make
```

---

Another possible solution: follow this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) to install pip2.7, then use pip2.7 to install everything (uwsgi, Django, ...).
The guide also introduces **virtualenv**, it's a strongly recommended tool for development with Python. As the name indicates, it creates separate "python package spaces", so you can have different versions of Django or any Python packages in a computer, for different projects.

Comment: Thank you :). I am done with it. Now there is another error.

`Set PythonHome to /usr/local/.localpython/bin/python
ImportError: No module named site`

Do I need to set the environment variable?

Comment: I haven't seen this error. You may try "-H ......" to set PythonHome for uwsgi. If you're using Virtualenv, the path will be under virtualenv folder. This answer mentioned about using "--no-site" parameter to solve the issue, you may also give a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417823/how-do-i-run-uwsgi-with-virtualenv/#18418014

Comment: The importError means that uwsgi can't find the modules it's looking for in the virtualenv.  Make sure the virtualenv path is correct.  make sure the modules are in the virtualenv.  Don't use the "--no-site" flag unless you aren't planning on using anything in 'site-packages'.