# uwsgi upstart on amazon linux

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, flask, uwsgi, upstart

I created a uwsgi file following this tutorial https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html on amazon linux. Though It doesn't seem to run as Nginx just says bad gateway. If I run the

/etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec /home/ec2-user/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/ec2-user/uwsgi-prod_demo.ini
```

if I do run the following in shell, then python application runs.

```
/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/ec2-user/uwsgi-prod_demo.ini
```

uwsgi-prod_demo.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = :8080
chdir = /home/ec2-user/prod_demo
master = True
venv = /home/ec2-user/venv
callable = app
wsgi-file = /home/ec2-user/prod_demo/manage.py
enable-threads = True
https = =0,/home/ec2-user/xxx.com.au.pem,/home/ec2-user/newkey.pem,HIGH
```

nginx.conf

```
user  ec2-user;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/ec2-user/xxx.com.au.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ec2-user/newkey.pem;
    server_name import.xxx.com.au  *.import.xxx.com.au;
    access_log /var/log/prod_demo/access_log;

    root /home/ec2-user/prod_demo;

    location / {
      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
      include uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
         alias /home/ec2-user/prod_demo/app/static;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            alias    /home/ec2-user/prod_demo/app/static/images/favicon.ico;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix this I did a few things. 
- Moved all scripts from the home directory to an /var/www/
- created an www group and www user and chown /var/www to www:www

Full Instructions

1. Create a user and group www and www

   ```
   sudo groupadd www
   sudo adduser www -g www
   ```
2. create a dir where your flask application will be ie /var/www/

   ```
   sudo chown -R www:www /var/www
   ```
3. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   ```
   # /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   # For more information on configuration, see:
   #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
   #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

   user  www;
   worker_processes  1;

   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
   #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

   pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


   events {
       worker_connections  1024;
   }


   http {
       include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type  application/octet-stream;

       log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                         '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                         '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

       sendfile        on;
       #tcp_nopush     on;
       client_max_body_size 20M;

       #keepalive_timeout  0;
       keepalive_timeout  0;

       uwsgi_read_timeout 86400;
       uwsgi_send_timeout 86400;

       #gzip  on;

       # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
       # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
       # for more information.
       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

     server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /var/www/test.com.au.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /var/www/newkey.pem;
       server_name demo.test.com.au;
       access_log /var/log/prod_demo/access_log;

       root /var/www/prod_demo;

       location / {
         uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:28080;
         include uwsgi_params;
       }

       location /static {
            alias /var/www/prod_demo/app/static;
       }

       location = /favicon.ico {
               alias    /var/www/prod_demo/app/static/images/favicon.ico;
       }
     }

     server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /var/www/test.com.au.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /var/www/newkey.pem;
       server_name ajtravel.test.com.au;
       access_log /var/log/prod_demo_two/access_log;

       root /var/www/prod_demo_two;

       location / {
         uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:28082;
         include uwsgi_params;
       }

       location /static {
            alias /var/www/prod_demo_two/app/static;
       }

       location = /favicon.ico {
               alias    /var/www/prod_demo_two/app/static/images/favicon.ico;
       }
     }

      #test config

     server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /var/www/test.com.au.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /var/www/newkey.pem;
       server_name demo.test.test.com.au;
       access_log /var/log/prod_demo/access_log;

       root /var/www/prod_demo;

       location / {
         uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:28080;
         include uwsgi_params;
       }

       location /static {
            alias /var/www/prod_demo/app/static;
       }

       location = /favicon.ico {
               alias    /var/www/prod_demo/app/static/images/favicon.ico;
       }
     }

     server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /var/www/test.com.au.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /var/www/newkey.pem;
       server_name ajtravel.test.test.com.au;
       access_log /var/log/prod_demo_two/access_log;

       root /var/www/prod_demo_two;

       location / {
         uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:28082;
         include uwsgi_params;
       }

       location /static {
            alias /var/www/prod_demo_two/app/static;
       }

       location = /favicon.ico {
               alias    /var/www/prod_demo_two/app/static/images/favicon.ico;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. /etc/init/uwsgi-prod-demo.conf

   ```
   # https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html
   # /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
   # simple uWSGI script

   description "uwsgi tiny instance"
   #start on runlevel [2345]
   #stop on runlevel [06]

   start on started elastic-network-interfaces

   exec /var/www/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/uwsgi-prod_demo.ini
   ```
5. /var/www/uwsgi-prod_demo.ini

   ```
   [uwsgi]
   uid = www
   gid = www
   socket = :28080
   chdir = /var/www/prod_demo
   master = True
   venv = /var/www/venv
   callable = app
   wsgi-file = /var/www/prod_demo/manage.py
   enable-threads = True
   ```

Comment: I use user ec2 group www-data , is that ok.I found move project file under /var/www/ is a very good practice.

Comment: @tyan I'm still no expert on this security, though I do not think this is a good idea. In the event of an security flaw in your application the user may be able to elevate themselves to root. The www user I set up can not use the su.

Comment: but nginx defaults to www-data on ubuntu . why should we set up another usr and a new group instead of use the default >