# uwsgi + nginx + flask: upstream prematurely closed

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I created an endpoint on my flask which generates a spreadsheet from a database query (remote db) and then sends it as a download in the browser. Flask doesn't throw any errors. Uwsgi doesn't complain.

But when I check nginx's error.log I see a lot of

> 2014/12/10 05:06:24 [error] 14084#0: *239436 upstream prematurely
>   closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   34.34.34.34, server: me.com, request: "GET /download/export.csv HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://0.0.0.0:5002", host: "me.com", referrer:
>   "https://me.com/download/export.csv"

I deploy the uwsgi like

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5002 --buffer-size=32768 --module server --callab app
```

my nginx config:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     merge_slashes off;
     server_name me.com www.me.cpm;

     location / { try_files $uri @app; }
       location @app {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;
          uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
          uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
          uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
     }

}

server {
      listen 443;
      merge_slashes off;
      server_name me.com www.me.com;

    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
       location @app {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;
          uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
          uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
          uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
       }
}
```

Is this an nginx or uwsgi issue, or both?

Comment: I once got the same error, it turned to be that I forgot "include uwsgi_params". or check your `uwsgi_params`  file under nginx confs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change nginx.conf to include

```
sendfile        on;
client_max_body_size 20M;
keepalive_timeout  0;
```

See self answer [uwsgi upstart on amazon linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196776/uwsgi-upstart-on-amazon-linux) for full example

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned by @mahdix, the error can be caused by Nginx sending a request with the uwsgi protocol while uwsgi is listening on that port for http packets.

When in the Nginx config you have something like:

```
upstream org_app {
    server              10.0.9.79:9597;
}
location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      org_app;
}
```

Nginx will use the uwsgi protocol. But if in `uwsgi.ini` you have something like (or its equivalent in the command line):

```
http-socket=:9597
```

uwsgi will *speak* http, and the error mentioned in the question appears. See [native HTTP support](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html).

A possible fix is to have instead:

```
socket=:9597
```

In which case Nginx and uwsgi will communicate with each other using the uwsgi protocol over a TCP connection.

Side note: if Nginx and uwsgi are in the same node, a Unix socket will be faster than TCP. See [using Unix sockets instead of ports](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html?highlight=unix%20socket#using-unix-sockets-instead-of-ports).

Answer (score 5):

In my case, problem was nginx was sending a request with uwsgi protocol while uwsgi was listening on that port for http packets. So either I had to change the way nginx connects to uwsgi or change the uwsgi to listen using uwsgi protocol.

Comment: Could you please add the details of your solution to your answer? I believe you either need to use `uwsgi_pass` and then set the `socket` value to the port in the uwsgi .ini file OR `proxy_pass` in nginx along with setting `http-socket` to the port in uwsgi?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same sporadic errors in Elastic Beanstalk single-container Docker WSGI app deployment. On EC2 instance of the environment upstream configuration looks like:

```
upstream docker {
    server 172.17.0.3:8080;
    keepalive 256;
}
```

With this default upstream simple load test like:

```
siege -b -c 16 -t 60S -T 'application/json' 'http://host/foo POST {"foo": "bar"}'
```

...on the EC2 led to availability of ~70%. The rest were 502 errors caused by *upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream*.

The solution was to either remove `keepalive` setting from the upstream configuration, or which is easier and more reasonable, is to enable HTTP keep-alive at `uWSGI`'s side as well, with `--http-keepalive` ([available since 1.9](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog-1.9.html#http-router-keepalive-auto-chunking-auto-gzip-and-transparent-websockets)).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;` with `uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5002;` or better use unix sockets.

Answer (score 1):

It seems many causes can stand behind this error message. I know you are using `uwsgi_pass`, but for those having the problem on long requests when using `proxy_pass`, setting `http-timeout` on uWSGI may help (it is not harakiri setting).

Answer (score 1):

There are many potential causes and solutions for this problem. In my case, the back-end code was taking too long to run. Modifying these variables fixed it for me.

Nginx:
`proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_send_timeout`, `proxy_read_timeout`, `fastcgi_send_timeout`, `fastcgi_read_timeout`, `keepalive_timeout`, `uwsgi_read_timeout`, `uwsgi_send_timeout`, `uwsgi_socket_keepalive`.

uWSGI: `limit-post`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by passing `socket-timeout = 65` (uwsgi.ini file) or `--socket-timeout=65` (uwsgi command line) option in uwsgi. We have to check with different value depends on the web traffic. This value `socket-timeout = 65` in uwsgi.ini file worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reverting to `pip3 install uwsgi`.

I was trying out the setup with Ubuntu and Amazon Linux side by side. I initially used a virtual environment and did `pip3 install uwsgi` both systems work fine. Later, I did continue the setup with virtual env turned off. On Ubuntu I install using `pip3 install uwsgi` and on Amazon Linux `yum install uwsgi -y`. That was the source of the problem for me.

Ubuntu works fine, but not the Amazon Linux

The fix,

`yum remove uwsgi` and `pip3 install uwsgi` restart and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be caused by a mismatch between timeout values.
I had this issue when nginx had a `keepalive_timeout` of 75s, while the upstream server's value was a few seconds.

This caused the upstream server to close the connection when its timeout was reached, and nginx logged `Connection reset by peer` errors.

When having such abrupt "connection closed" errors, please check the upstream timeout values are higher than nginx' values (see [Raphael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396248/uwsgi-nginx-flask-upstream-prematurely-closed/63715007#63715007) for a good list to check)

Answer (score 0):

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/html/api
http-timeout = 600
http-socket-protocol = http/1.1
#http-socket-max-request = 69832  ==> comment this max-request
buffer-size = 32768
memory-report = 65536
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 2
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
#virtualenv = ../venv
#socket = /var/run/uwsgi.sock
module = api.wsgi:application
chmod-socket = 664
```

During using nginx proxy... comment or remove that line from UWSGI (http-socket-max-request)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the UWSGI setting from HTTP to SOCKET and the 502 error disappeared.
However, I still don't know why that fixed the problem.

If anyone has an explanation, I'd appreciate it.