# uwsgi upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream flask+uwsgi+nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy a flask project (uwsgi + Nginx) on ubuntu 20.04 server. For this I'm following [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04).

I get **502 bad gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)** error.

After checking nginx error logs I find

```
 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.37.157.148, server: 3.75.132.146, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/ubuntu/flask-app/webapp/flask-app.sock:", host: "3.75.132.146", referrer: "http://3.75.132.146/"
```

My .ini file includes:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
wsgi-file = /home/ubuntu/flask-app/webapp/wsgi.py
chdir = /home/ubuntu/flask-app/webapp/
protocol = http
#home = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/

master = true
processes = 5

limit-as = 512
uid = ubuntu
gid = www-data
socket = flask-app.sock

chown-socket = ubuntu
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

And my nginx config files includes:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 3.75.132.146;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/flask-app/webapp/static/;
    }
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/flask-app/webapp/flask-app.sock;
    }
}
```

I have been searching online and no one seems to have a solid solution for this. Please help me if anyone already faced this and **solved** this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uwsgi + nginx + flask: upstream prematurely closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396248/uwsgi-nginx-flask-upstream-prematurely-closed)

Comment: @NickODell. I tried some of the solutions presented in that forum. But they doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. did you find a solution for this? )))

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete 'protocol = http' from My.ini and add 'socket-timeout=36000'