# uWSGI, Flask and Parallel execution blocks

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a small API written in Python with Flask. It is a wrapper API around another API (which I don't control). I need to make several requests and I want to make them parallel. The first alternative was to use `grequests` but inexplicably the `uwsgi` server hanged and didn't respond. It took a while for it to reload workers after sending `HUP` signal to the master process. The code I was using is something like:

```
urls = [
    'http://www.example.com', 
    'http://www.example.net',
]
urls = [grequests.get(x, hooks=dict(response=function_to_do_some_work))
        for url in urls]
grequests.map(urls) # <- here it hangs
```

I thought it was some problem with `gevent`/`grequests` so I reimplemented the solution using `multiprocessing.Pool`, like this:

```
urls = [
    'http://www.example.com', 
    'http://www.example.net',
]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
pool.map(function_to_do_some_work, urls) # <- here it hangs
```

The problem here is not the code, that runs perfectly in the development environment. The problem is with the `uwsgi` and Python execution model, or something between those lines. I don't know where to start looking for answers here. The versions of the modules I'm using are:

```
Python 2.7.5
grequests 0.2.0
Flask 0.10.1
uwsgi 2.0.9
```

What alternative of parallel execution should I use to perform several tasks at the same time, under this execution environment?

Comment: Your application container (uWSGI, or whatever you want) need to know if you want to use a specific development paradigm. grequests needs a gevent hub, so uWSGI must be run in gevent mode. For using user-generated threads you need to enable them with enable-threads like explained in the first answer

Comment: I was having the same problem using `threading.Thread` + `uwsgi` and adding `enable-threads = true` worked like a charm! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threading needs to be enabled on uwsgi by

```
enable-threads = True
```

Full example of config of nginx, and uwsgi, upstart, virtual-env see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221427/567606