# "Internal Server Error" with POST requests on flask + gunicorn + nginx setup

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, internal-server-error

I am attempting to deploy a flask webapp on digital ocean, but I keep getting "internal server error" whenever I attempt to do anything involving POST requests (such as logging in or registering). The app works fine when I run it using flask's built-in server.

I used parts 1 & 2 in [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/) tutorial to set it up, with the exception of replacing flask_project with the name of my project, and newuser with my username. Does anybody know how I can fix this, or at the very least, go about diagnosing the problem? Are there error logs somewhere?

I notice the sample app used in the example only uses GET requests, which work fine. My guess is that I need to do configuration slightly differently in order to get POST to work as well. However, I can't find any tutorials on how to properly do this.

Thanks in advance

Update: So I wiped the sever clean and started over, this time using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) tutorial on how to deploy on apache. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Error might be related to what you are doing in the post message. Perhaps use a try: except block to capture all exception, and return the error might help you debug this.

Comment: I know the actual POST message isn't the issue because it works flawlessly when I run it using flask's internal server. Only when I try to do it through nginx do I get an error. This means there is something wrong with my nginx configuration that's causing to not pass PST requests it receives to gunicorn properly. Only, I don't know how to correctly configure it

Comment: @quantumbutterfly I just ran into a ton of these problems with nginx, flask and uwsgi. Can you put up your virtual server files? That way we can take a look and maybe help out a bit more.

Comment: @SJoshi Where do I find my virtual server files?

Comment: @quantumbutterfly could be still permissions related. I discovered this when I had this issue with my servers (not digital ocean)  until I created an user and group www http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221427/567606 Is this POST function writing anything to disk?

Comment: @darwindave when I run `sudo adduser www -g www`, I get `Option g is ambiguous (gecos, gid, group)`

Any ideas?

Comment: @quantumbutterfly did you complete the sudo groupadd www first. Did you choose to rename the group id (gid) to something else?

Comment: @darwindave yes, I did. So from reading the help, I found out users are added to groups without the -g flag. I ran the command `sudo adduser myusername www' and then `sudo chown -R myusername:www /var/www`, but that did not solve the issue

Comment: @quantumbutterfly I think you need to configure logging. I just used the mail logger like demonstrated in https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky . Look at config.py for the details under production config it will set up the email logging.

Comment: @quantumbutterfly your nginx virtual servers tend to be in something like /etc/nginx/sites-available/