# The uWSGI SPDY router setup

Tags: uwsgi, spdy

Following the instructions from the uWSGI [SPDY router](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SPDY.html) docs I didn't have much luck.

I've tried it on a vagrant instance `Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Under a virtual environment.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

Issuing following command that I derive from the manual does fire up a server:

```
$ uwsgi --master --https2 addr==0.0.0.0:8443,cert=/home/vagrant/server.crt,key=/home/vagrant/server.key,spdy=asdf --module werkzeug.testapp:test_app --thunder-lock --socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock --shared-socket :8443 -H /vagrant/venv/
```

Note that I'm forwarding host 8422 to guest 8443.

The problem is that checking `https://spdy.localhost:8442/` doesn't show any Werkzeug variables described in the manual (SPDY, SPDY.version). The `UWSGI_ROUTER` has value of "http" if that's of any significance.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

Werkzeug Version    0.10.4

uwsgi.version   '2.0.10'

I've made sure tat python doesn't produce [insecure platform](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning) warning.
The OpenSSL seems to be OK version according to the manual.
There are no warnings or meaningful info messages in the log.
It just doesn't use SPDY routing it seems.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: you might want to try to get things out of your home directory. Create an www user and group. get all certs / files into a dir that www own's using chown -R www:www .see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221427/567606

Comment: I ended up using fcgi through nginx.