# Serve dynamic media in Flask with Nginx+uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am really stuck with serving dynamically created content in Flask.

If I understand everything right, the only way to do it in Python code is to use Flask native send_file(). Is there a way to perform send_file not through Flask itself? It's extremely slow, I can't afford it :(

I know how to serve statics via nginx, but it seems to be not suitable in my case, cause it links a web address with the real path on my server. When I perform send_file(), the file does not have any web address (am I right?).

So, what should I do?

Comment: I had simular difficulties and I solved my issue and documented it http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221427/567606

Comment: When writing the post, I meant other difficulty cause everything was, at least, working in some way. But now I really have trouble with Upstart. You are from FBI, aren't you?

Comment: steps 1 and 2 were required for upstart as using the default user was a problem. It was a step I missed out thinking it was unnecessary, though once I did nginx uwsgi and upstart started to work. Not from fbi I'm an ex .NET dev that had a lot of trouble making the switch! To be fair I had lots of trouble debugging IIS back in the day too. At least this way its all scriptable and repeatable with linux once you get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go read about `X-Accel-Redirect` response header and how that can be used in conjunction with a nginx front end to have nginx serve up a file which has been written to the file system by a backend web application.

- http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel

Comment: Thanx, Graham! Don't even know, how it was possible not to google it before.