# `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'` when import psutil module

Tags: python, virtualenv, psutil

In my flask project, I use `uwsgi` run it.

in my project there has `import psutil`.

off course I installed latest psutil in my venv:

```
(venv) [root@7338cdd80407 ssl-node]# pip3 install --upgrade psutil
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /www/wwwroot/ssl-node/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (5.8.0)
```

but when I execute my flask code, there get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'`:

```
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 703600 bytes (687 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
added /www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/ to pythonpath.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/manager.py", line 9, in <module>
    from api import app
  File "/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from utils import utils, util_check_pem_key_cert
  File "/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/utils/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .util_process import (
  File "/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/utils/util_process.py", line 6, in <module>
    import psutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

---

**EDIT-01**

my `pip3` and `pip` both comes from `venv`:

```
(venv) [root@7338cdd80407 ssl-node]# which pip3
/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/venv/bin/pip3
(venv) [root@7338cdd80407 ssl-node]# which pip 
/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/venv/bin/pip
```

---

**EDIT-02**

My python3 path:

```
(venv) [root@7338cdd80407 ssl-node]# which python3
/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/venv/bin/python3
```

I use `uwsgi -d --ini uwsgi_prod.ini` execute my flask project:

`uwsgi_prod.ini` content:

```
[uwsgi]
http=0.0.0.0:5000
processes=4
threads=2
master=true
pythonpath=/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node
module=manager
callable=app
memory-report=true
buffer-size=32768
static-map=/static=/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/static
daemonize=/www/wwwroot/ssl-node/ssl-node/log/uwsgi.log
```

you see there execute from `manager.py`:
the content of it:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# Author: jack

import sys,os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(path)

from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: When you do `which pip3` or `where pip3` do you get the output as the one inside your venv?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami both comes from `venv`, check my edit.

Comment: How do you execute your flask code? If you run like `python3 some file.py` can you check `where python3`

Comment: updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `uwsgi` is not being run from inside the vent. To do so run the application with:

```sh
uwsgi -d --ini uwsgi_prod.ini -H /www/wwwroot/ssl-node/venv/bin/python3
```

See a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417823/how-do-i-run-uwsgi-with-virtualenv) or the documentation [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python.html#virtualenv-support)